# How to get vscode to show my python venv listed in the interpreters list?

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, virtualenv

I use vscode for python dev on mac. in one of my projects I don't see the venv python listed in the "Select Interpreter" to select. When I use the "find" option to go to the venv/bin/python and select it it'd revert back and doesn't seem to have any effect.

[image]

How do I get vscode to show venv?

I'm using macOS Catalina
vscode 1.54.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the fix for this:
after reading this:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/wiki/AB-Experiments
I added  "python.experiments.enabled": false to
~/Library/Application\ Support/Code/User/settings.json
and it fixed the issue.

hopefully it'll help other folks who run into this.